# SQL - query by dynamic weights

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a database with users that have a list of items.
Simple design:

**Users:**

UserStuff | UserID

**ItemsList:**

itemID | UserID

Each user has a list of items. An Item can belong to many users (same itemID, different userID).

Now I want to give weights to the items dynamically (calculated at runtime, not something constant that can be stored in the database) and then Select the users with the highest weights according to their Items.

Can I give the weight to the items in an SQL query, and then do the calculation ?

I'm trying to avoid looping through the database and calculating the users' weights.

**Edit:**

example:

**UserStuff** | **UserID**
blah1         |  1
blah2         |  2

**itemID** | **UserID**
1          |    1
1          |    2
2          |    1
3          |    1
4          |    2
5          |    1

wieghts:
itemId = 1 = 15
itemID = 2 = 10

UserID1 total weight = 25
UserID2 total weight = 10

Comment: Could you clarify with an example?

Comment: Will all the inputs required for calculating the weights be stored in the database?  Or does the application/client have to specifically supply these values?

Comment: The application calculates the weights externally. It can't be calculated from information in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a temporary table of weights, with your dynamic values:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE weights(item_id integer, weight integer);
CREATE TABLE
INSERT INTO weights VALUES (1, 10);  -- Inserting weights
INSERT 0 1
INSERT INTO weights VALUES (2, 1);   -- Inserting weights
INSERT 0 1
...
```

Create a view to map items to weights:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW items_weights AS 
       SELECT il.itemID, il.UserID, w.weight FROM
              ItemsList il JOIN weights w 
              ON il.itemID=w.item_id;
```

Select the highest-weighted users:

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(weight) FROM items_weights
       GROUP BY UserId ORDER BY COUNT(weight) DESC;
```

Comment: Can it be done with a view or something instead of a temp table ? If there are a lot of threads working and doing the same thing it will be a mess of temporary tables.

Comment: +1, @Yochai Timmer: SQL Databases work with temporary tables all the time, for example when doing a join, subquery or other calculation.  Temp tables perform well under heavy concurrency.